# Scala Array constructor?

Tags: scala, arrays, scala-2.8

```
scala> val a = Array [Double] (10)
a: Array[Double] = Array(10.0)

scala> val a = new Array [Double] (10)
a: Array[Double] = Array(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Why these two expressions have different semantics?

Comment: Array managing in Scala is a pest.. only possible if you are developing on a frozen base

Comment: A "frozen base?" It's true array treatment changed considerably from 2.7 to 2.8, but I think we can expect it to remain stable hereafter. Now Scala Array is Java Array. Scala's "extra" array functionality is handled via implicits.

Comment: How do the implicts allow Array to get more functionality ?

Comment: You can write something like `Array(1,2,3).map(_ * 0.5)` and it will work exactly as if `Array` were a standard part of the Scala collections.  But behind the scenes, it's implicitly placed into a wrapper class, and that wrapper is what calls `map`.  So, on the one hand, `Array[X]` really is Java's `X[]`, and on the other, you can pretend it's an almost-completely-integrated member of Scala's collections.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's a bit confusing, but Scala has the notion of *classes* which you can create instances of, and *objects*, which are basically singleton instances of a class. It also has the notion of *companion classes*, which is a pair of a class and an object with the same name. This mechanism allows a "class" to essentially have static methods, which are otherwise not possible in Scala.

`Array` has both a *class* and a companion *object*. Furthermore, the [`Array` object](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/Array$object.html) has an `apply` method. `apply` means you can create an object with `Array(arg)`. But because `Array` is a companion class, it also has a constructor that can be called via the more usual mechanism of `new Array(arg)`.

The issue is that `apply` in the the `Array` object has different semantics than the `Array` constructors. The `apply` method creates an array out of the specified objects, so, for example, `Array(1,2,3)` returns an array consisting of the objects `1`, `2`, and `3`. The constructors, on the other hand, take arguments that specify the size of the dimensions of the array (so you can create multidimensional arrays), and then initialize all slots to a default value.

So, basically:

- `val a = Array [Double] (10)` calls the `apply` method on the `Array` *object*, which creates a new array containing the given objects.
- `val a = new Array [Double] (10)` calls the `Array` constructor, which creates a new array with 10 slots, all initialized to a default value of `0.0`.

Comment: @mipadi, how to create a new array with 10 slots and 1 as default value? Thanks

Comment: @city `val a = Array.fill(10){1}`

Answer (score 11):

`new Array[Double](10)` is supposed to be equivalent to `new double[10]` in Java.

But Scala also provides convenience methods on the singletons corresponding to its collection classes, and `Array` is no exception.

Thus, if you can say `List(1,2,3,4,5)` it seems natural that you could also say `Array(1,2,3,4,5)`.  And you can.

But it does leave one in the slightly awkward position of having rather different results depending on whether one adds the word `new` or not.  Given the competing interests, I think it's the best solution overall, but it does take a little getting used to.